# How to call the parent class's destructor from inside a child class?

Tags: php, class

Is there any way to call the **parent class's default destructor** from **inside a child class** so that none of the members of the parent class remain active **for a particular instance of the child class**?

In this case **no destructor is defined** for the parent class. This may come to use if there are many member variables of the parent class. Then this method would be more useful than using **unset()** for each member variable.

Is there any possible solution?

Comment: why `parent::__destruct();`?

Comment: If you're trying to call destructor in constructor, it is a 99.9% architecture glitch. In your case - you're trying to destroy parent context from child instance. Why?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo and say if i need it anyway in another context how to do it?

Comment: @RajeshPaul to destroy whole parent context? Why do such thing? If you want to unset single property - then it (may be, but I doubt even that) a normal case.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: ya that is possible i.e. by unset() for each and every property of the parent class.

I was just concerned about any way to call the default destructor of the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor function gets called automatically when the objects has had its last call.

> Like constructors, parent destructors will not be called implicitly by
>   the engine. In order to run a parent destructor, one would have to
>   explicitly call parent::__destruct() in the destructor body. Also like
>   constructors, a child class may inherit the parent's destructor if it
>   does not implement one itself. - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

So you can call a parent::__destructor from a public function __destructor from the child class and not from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `__destruct()` function defined for the main class (which can be also called `parent` form extended class), therefore, calling `parent::__destruct();` produces valid and expected fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method c1::__destruct()
```

You can use `self::__destruct();` or `$this->__destruct()`

If you want to add __destrcut() to the parent then do:

```
class c1
{
    public $a=10;
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Called Construct_c1()<br>";
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo "Called Destruct_c1()<br>";
    }
}
```

And now its available for `parent::__destruct();` call

Comment: :but my concern is to call the default destructor of the parent class from child class, not necessarily from the child class's constructor.